# Getting divs to close if another one opens with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

Basically I have signup and signin and I they're both divs which appear and disappear on the click of a link but I wish for one to close if the other is clicked and then opened.

Example:
signin area is open and signup button is clicked. I wish for signin area to disappear and for the signup content to be revealed.

Current Code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("signin");
    var text = document.getElementById("signtext");
    var ele2 = document.getElementById("signup");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("signuptext");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
        ele2.style.display = "block";
        text2.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
        ele2.style.display = "block";
        text2.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
}
function toggle2() {
    var ele2 = document.getElementById("signup");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("signuptext");
    var ele = document.getElementById("signin");
    var text = document.getElementById("signtext");
    if(ele2.style.display == "block") {
        ele2.style.display = "none";
        text2.innerHTML = "show";   
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
    else {
        ele2.style.display = "block";
        text2.innerHTML = "hide";
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }   
} 
</script>
```

Html :

```
<div id="signin" style="display: none">
<form action="loginscript.php" method="post">
<p>Username:<input type="text" id="username"></p>
<p>Password:<input type="password" id="password"> <input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
</div>
<div id="signup" style="display: none">
<h1>peek-a-boo</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: use of `<script language="javascript">` has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Try this.There is no need of creating two different functions.Lesser the number of functions=Better the code + smarter is the coder!!!!

```
function toggle(id){

switch(id)
{
case 'signin':
document.getElementById('signin').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('signup').style.display='none';
break;

case 'signup':
document.getElementById('signup').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('signin').style.display='none';
break;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="signin" onclick="toggle(this.id)"> SignIN</div>
<div id="signup" onclick="toggle(this.id)"> SignUp</div>
```

Comment: @user:this is just the basic idea,the logic for your desired functionality.You got to push yourself a little and manipulate your code accordingly!!!This is a perfect according to me.Give me your fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function signUpIn(objId) {
   document.getElementById('signin').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('signup').style.display = 'none';

   document.getElementById(objId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Your html changes:

```
<div id="signin" style="display: block">

</div>    
<div id="signup" style="display: none">
</div>

<a href="javascript: signUpIn('signup');">Sign Up</a>
<a href="javascript: signUpIn('signin');">Sign In</a>
```

Check if it works for you.

Comment: Is it tagged with `jQuery` ?

Comment: @swapnesh, now i have changed my answer as per tags

Comment: As a note - this one is consider as a bad practice `javascript: signUpIn('signup');` instead attach an event handler to the element

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a function on "onclick" event and hide the div using `CSS:Visibility` property

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="MyFunction();">link text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab concept from this, may not be a perfect, but still contain some learning part -

Check this working **Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/j7LDD/

**Working Code** -

HTML PART -

```
<form id="signup" method="get" style="display:none;">
<label>SignUp Name</label>
<input type="text" name="signupname" />
<input type="submit" name="signupsubmit" value="signup" />
</form>

<form id="signin" method="get" style="display:none;">
<label>SignIn Name</label>
<input type="text" name="signinname" />
<input type="submit" name="signinsubmit" value="signin" />
</form>

<button id="signupbutton" onclick="toggle(this.id);">SignUp</button>
<button id="signinbutton" onclick="toggle(this.id);">SignIn</button>
```

JS PART -

```
<script>
function toggle( val ) {
    if( "signupbutton" == val ) {
    document.getElementById("signup").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("signup").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```